# setInterval Stacks on rapid Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, setinterval, clearinterval

I am trying to create a generic timer stop watch effect when the user clicks on an image.  I am utilizing fancybox v2.0.  The intended goal is to trigger the timer effect as soon as the image has been clicked on and the ‘zoomed’ image has been loaded.  Then, when the user escapes the ‘zoomed’ image view, the timer should stop.  Ultimately, I just want to capture the amount of TOTAL time that the image was in a ‘zoomed’ state.
For the most part, it is working as intended, but there is a glitch that can be forced;  If you click on the fancybox() image in rapid succession, deliberately, (with the only intended result of triggering the glitch) there are times where the setInterval() will NOT clear and will, seemingly, stack with itself.  The result is that the interval duration is doubled and the onClick() sequencing is thrown off somehow.  The glitch will only happen in the ‘zoomed’ state, so try to time your rapid clicking with that in mind.

http://www.alexldixon.com/clicktimerhelp.htm

```
        frontImage.click(function () {              
            //$('.fancybox-overlay').addClass('Closing');
                var frontTimer = setInterval(function(f) {
                    frontVar[0] = frontVar[0] + delay;
                    frontCover.val(frontVar/100);
                    if(($('.fancybox-overlay').is(":visible") === true)  && ($('div.Closing').length > 0))
                    {
                        frontCover.css("background-color", "green");
                        $('.fancybox-overlay, .fancybox-close').click(function () { 
                            $('.fancybox-overlay').removeClass('Closing');
                            frontCover.val(frontCover.val());
                            clearInterval(frontTimer);                  
                            frontCover.css("background-color", "yellow");
                            clearInterval(fancyOverlay);
                        });
                    } else {
                            $('.fancybox-overlay').removeClass('Closing');
                            clearInterval(frontTimer);
                            clearInterval(fancyOverlay);
                            frontCover.css("background-color", "yellow");
                        } 
                }, 1000);               

                var fancyOverlay = setInterval(function(sniffOverlay) {
                        $('div.fancybox-overlay:eq(0)').addClass('Closing');
                        return frontTimer;
                    }, 50);
                return fancyOverlay;
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make another variable that would more quickly search for, find, and trigger the stop watch effect.  To do this, I removed the addClass on click functionality and rather put it in a conditional new interval that will run on click, indefinitely, until the fancybox overlay is generated.  This ensures that regardless of the actual timer function, the condition 'sniffer' will always work on intended, regardless of click speed or function sequencing; because I don't I can click 0 milliseconds per second...

```
frontImage.click(function () {
    var frontTimer = setInterval(function(f) {
        frontVar[0] = frontVar[0] + delay;
        frontCover.val(frontVar/100);
        if(($('.fancybox-overlay').is(":visible") === true)  && ($('div.Closing').length > 0))
        {
            frontCover.css("background-color", "green");
            $('.fancybox-overlay, .fancybox-close').mouseup(function () {
                frontImage.removeClass('Closing');
                frontCover.val(frontCover.val());
                clearInterval(frontTimer);
                frontCover.css("background-color", "yellow");
            });
        } else {
                frontImage.removeClass('Closing');
                clearInterval(frontTimer);
                frontCover.css("background-color", "yellow");
            }
    }, 1000);

    var fancyOverlay = setInterval(function(sniffOverlay) {
        if($('div.fancybox-overlay:eq(0)').length === 0)
        {
            frontImage.removeClass('Closing');
            frontCover.css("background-color", "yellow");
            frontCover.val(frontCover.val());
            clearInterval(frontTimer);
        } else {                            
            frontImage.addClass('Closing');
            return frontTimer;                      
        }
    }, 0);
});
```